# matplotlib Value Error:

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a graph using part of an example as a reference, the problem I'm having is the graph reads from a `.txt` file and the data inside is formatted like this:

11.0 24:59:59

11.5 24:59:59

1.0 24:59:59

etc
etc

I'd like this data to be shown on the graph, the code I'm working with is this:

```
def animate(i):
pullData = open("sampleText.txt","r").read()
dataList = pullData.splitlines()
xList = []
yList = []



for eachLine in dataList:
    if len(eachLine) > 1:
        x, y = eachLine.split(',')
        xList.append(int(x))
        yList.append(int(y))


a.clear()
a.plot(xList, yList)
```

the above current work if the `.txt` file is formatted like this:

1,3

2,8

3,7

4,8

I would appreciate some help here, thank you.,,

so now i have the graph reading the data in the correct format and plotting in on the graph. the problem in facing now is sometimes my arduino will send a blank text file if it dont get a reading in time and this results in the graph code crashing throwing an exception and needs more than 1 value. the arduino sends a text file sensdata.txt and the python script opens it reads the content and prints in in another text file sensdata-log.txt line after line. so it ends up looking like this,

```
10.0
5.0
20.0
```

but sometimes it will log the blank reading like this and it causes the graph to crash,

```
11.0
blank** space when no erading
10.0
5.0
```

how can i prevent the script from updating sensdata-log.txt when sensdata.txt is blank? the method im using to open the files is,

```
    def Log(self):
     with open('sensdata.txt') as f: 
        FILE2 = f.read()

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
     if self.LogUpdate == 1:
        t = threading.Timer(1, self.Log) #every 45 minutes
        t.start()
        #print "disabled"
     if self.LogUpdate == 0:  
        p = open( 'sensdata-Log.txt', 'a' ) #(w= write)(a= append add lines)
        p.write(str(self.count) + ' ' + FILE2 + '\n')
        #print "itworks"
        self.count+=1 #to tell the graph next line
        #print self.count
        p.close()
        t = threading.Timer(60, self.Log) #
        t.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix your indentation and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `a` in your code and why is the parameter `i` not used?

Comment: sorry i didnt realize the comments below i wont let that happen again im going to update my first questing right now

Comment: No problem, editing questions is encouraged to improve them. And please delete your non-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
for eachLine in dataList:
    if len(eachLine) > 1:
        x, y = eachLine.split()   #split by space
        xList.append(float(x))    #convert to float
        yList.append(y)           #Time
```